# How do I insert json code in a specific area in python?

Tags: python, json

How do I insert data from a json dump to a specific area and not just the end of the file?

For example, if I have a json file:

```
{
  "name":"John Doe",
  "gender": "M",
  "married": true,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Mark Doe",
      "age": 5,
      "gender": "M"
    }
  ]
}
```

As wierd as it sounds, if John Doe had another child, and I had a python program which will add the child to the json file, I would do this, right?:

```
import json

with open("johnsjson.json", "a") as f:
  suzydoe = {"name": "Suzy", "age": 5, "gender": "F"}
  json.dump(suzydoe, f)
f.close()
```

But, if I do that, it gives an output:

```
{
  "name":"John Doe",
  "gender": "M",
  "married": true,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Mark Doe",
      "age": 5,
      "gender": "M"
    }
  ]
} {"name":"Suzy","age":5,"gender":"F"}
```

But, I want it to insert the json into the Children object. Can anyone help.
*and also, the code above is just an example to my actual code*

*Edit: Typo in the "children" formatting*

Comment: I think you would want to read the file, parse the JSON, modify the data, and then write it back as JSON again. Do you know how to do any of that?

Comment: You have a problem of format for children. Values are not regular dict

Comment: Opening with ` "a" ` will just **append** to the end of the file.

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo, but your `children` member is formatted incorrectly - the `{}` and `[]` brackets should be switched.

Answer (score 3):

You need to reformat your children value

```py
{"name":"John Doe",
 "gender": "M",
 "married": true,
 "children":
    [{"name":"Mark Doe",
      "age": 5,
      "gender": "M"}]}
```

and do that :

```py
import json

with open("johnsjson.json", "r+") as f:
  myJson = json.load(f)
  suzydoe = {"name": "Suzy", "age": 5, "gender": "F"}
  myJson["children"].append(suzydoe)
  f.seek(0)
  f.truncate()
  json.dump(myJson,f)
```

Comment: @rivamarco thanks for edits, I'm not used using files. Learned a lot.

Comment: what does the f.truncate() function do?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned your initial JSON format for children has the bracket the wrong way around and should be so that you have a children array `[]` of child objects `{}`:

```
{
  "name":"John Doe",
  "gender": "M",
  "married": true,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Mark Doe",
      "age": 5,
      "gender": "M"
    }
  ]
}
```

To answer your question, you will need to load the JSON file, amend it then write back to the file:

```
import json

with open("johnsjson.json", "r") as json_file:
    john = json.load(json_file)

    suzy_doe = {"name": "Suzy Doe", "age": 5, "gender": "F"}
    john['children'].append(suzy_doe)

with open("johnsjson.json", "w") as json_file: 
    json.dump(john, json_file)
```

There may be quicker ways but this works for me.

Comment: With the `with` context managers, you don't need to explicitly call `json_file.close()` - that's the whole purpose of `with`, it ensures that the resource is properly cleaned up.